# How to add unit test case for subscribe in angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine

My component.ts looks like this :

```
export class AlertComp implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
var1: string ;
var2: string ;
var3: string ;
sub:Subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;

constructor(........){
this.sub=AppService.appMessage$.subscribe(data => {
    this.var1=data[0];
    this.var2=data[1];
    this.var3=data[2];
});
```

My service.ts file looks like this :

```
export class AppService {
private appsub = new Subject<[string, string, boolean]>();
appMessage$ = this.appsub.asObservable();

showTestmessage(var1: string, var2:boolean =false) {
    this.appsub.next([var1, "test", var2]);
  }

}
```

I'm not sure how can I add unit test for the subscribe in component.spec.ts file

Answer (score 0):

Use a stub as shown below:

```js
// stub:
class AppServiceStub {
showTestmessage() { return of(your_data) }
}

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
providers: [{provide: AppService, useClass: AppServiceStub}]
})
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```